# The previous version of the electron app is loaded after updating the app using auto-updater

Tags: reactjs, electron, auto-update, electron-builder

I have integrated the electron app with the auto-updater and published the electron app as well. I am able to receive the newer version pop-up and able to upgrade my electron app but when I relaunch the installed electron app the app shows the previous version information and asks to install the newer version again. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I bumped across your question because I was having the same issue. I was using auto-updater with Quasar framework. Maybe this could help someone else.

Since **nsis** was configured by default to do the oneClick installations (with predefined rules), it was always installing my application somewhere in users/AppData folders, which I didn't even notice.

The thing I was running over and over again (after successfully auto-updating application) was actually installing the previous version all over again.

To circumvent this issue, I changed nsis configuration to allow users to select their own installation path.

```
nsis: {
    oneClick: false,
    allowToChangeInstallationDirectory: true
}
```

After this, app shortcut was appearing on desktop, which was always running the latest version.